# opening and immediately closing a tab after clicking links

Tags: web

When I click my homepage URL it opens in new tab and closes immediately.

It is working for product links but its not working for Main page URL.

There are some links posted in Facebook when I clicked on it,it opens and closes automatically.

Example: http://www.aido.com/eshop/cl_2-pr_11784512-i_11788010/12-years-a-slave-blu-ray.html - works properly.

http://www.aido.com/ -- This link is getting closed when clicked through from some sources like Facebook, Thunderboard

Comment: General cleanup. I'm unsure if Thunderboard means Thunderbird?

Comment: removed jboss and apache tags as the question do not relate to those in any way.

Answer (score 0):

it's adblock (try pausing it)

[people reporting the problem on the adblock website](https://support.getadblock.com/discussions/problems/79284-adblock-closing-tabs-without-asking)

Comment: tried incognito and disabled adblock, the issue still persists